# How to join list in tuple in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

**The list of tuples with a list in each tuple:**

```
[('22', ['de', 're']), ('11', ['c']), ('8, ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])]
```

I've got it after sorted my dict

```
dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])

return dictionary
```

I wonder if the following actually could be done
The goal is to get from this:

```
[('8, ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']), ('11', ['c']), ('22', ['de', 're'])]
```

This:

```
[('8', 'a, b, d, e'), ('11', 'c'), ('22', 'de, re')]
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string join", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
lst=[('11', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']), ('22', ['c']), ('8', ['de', 're'])]

res=list(map(lambda x: tuple([x[0]]+ [", ".join([el for el in x[1]])]), lst))

print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[('11', 'a, b, d, e'), ('22', 'c'), ('8', 'de, re')]
[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [`tuple()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tuple-function/) function? This function takes an iterable of some sort (in your case, a list) and returns a tuple with the values in that list.

Answer (score 0):

This comprehension should be what you’re looking for:

```
lst = [('11', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']), ('22', ['c']), ('8', ['de', 're'])]
res = [(n, ', '.join(s)) for n, s in lst]

print(res)
```

Prints:

```
[('11', 'a, b, d, e'), ('22', 'c'), ('8', 'de, re')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFun(t):
    return int(t[0])
a = [('22', ['de', 're']), ('11', ['c']), ('8', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])]
sorted(a, key=myFun)
```

Output- [('8', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']), ('11', ['c']), ('22', ['de', 're'])]
you can try this